# How to use const_reference type to declare a variable and assign to it, the return value of front() function

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I declared a vector and initialized it with three values as,

```
vector<int> vec{1, 2, 3};
```

I tried to assign the returned value of vec.front() to a reference variable, `a`.

How can I declare a using correct data type?

I tried,

```
vector<int>::const_reference &a = vec.front();
```

but what does this statement mean?

Can I first declare the variable a using proper data type and then use

```
a = vec.front();
```

to assign the returned value of vec.front() to the variable `a`? If yes, then what should I write?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I first declare the variable a using proper data type and then use

`a = vec.front();`

> to assign the returned value of vec.front() to the variable `a`

`a` isn't a normal variable; it's a reference, and it's not legal to declare a reference without also stating what it refers to:

```
const int& a;  // Illegal
```

Once a reference is declared, all operations performed on the variable are actually performed on the value it references, so you can't ever change what a reference references.

```
const int& a = b;
a = 10;  // Changed the value of b.
```

> I tried, `vector<int>::const_reference &a = vec.front();`

That seems an overly verbose way of saying:

```
const int& a = vec.front();
```

`vec.front()` returns a reference to the front element of the vector. `const int& a = vec.front()` declares variable `a` such that it is a reference to the front element of the vector.

That avoids copying by promising to read-only the value.

If you said:

```
int a = vec.front();
```

`a` would now be a copy of the first element of the array, but you are free to change it.

In the case of an int, there's no performance advantage. But if your vector was a vector of `string`s, taking a reference would avoid copying the string which could be a significant performance benefit over a reference if you don't intend to modify the contents.

```
std::string str = "hello world, this is a long string.";
const std::string& a = str;  // Reference, no copy
std::string b = str;  // Copy of str, takes extra effort
```

Answer (score 2):

`vector::front()` returns a reference to the first element in a vector. So you can declare a reference of the type you store in the vector or you can use the types defined in the vector class (`vector<int>::reference` or `vector<int>::const_reference`) to declare the reference.

```
   vector <int> v1;

   v1.push_back(10);
   v1.push_back(11);

   vector<int>::reference var1 = v1.front( ); // Returns a reference to the first element you can modify or
   int& x = v1.front(); // returns a reference to the first element you can modify

    .....

    vector<int>::const_reference var2 = v1.front(); // Returns a reference to the first element you can't modify
    const int& y = v1.front(); // Return a reference to the first element you can't modify
```

> Can I first declare the variable a using proper data type and then use

No. Since you are declaring a reference, it must be initialized during declaration.

One more thing:

```
    vector<int>::const_reference &a=v1.front(); // This will not compile, because you are trying to take a reference of a reference
```

Comment: I want to know that if i want to declare a variable var of type const_reference than is it necessary to write  vector<int>::const_reference &var,                               why can't i just write const_reference &var

Comment: @Aditya Yes you can declare it like that but without the &, like `vector<int>::const_reference var`. but it is the same as declaring `const int& var`

Answer (score 0):

Besides the good answer by @kfsone, there is a (let me say) trick to do something similar to what you are asking.
I'd do everything, but what I'm showing you below.
Anyway, for the sake of completeness, if you have around a `reference_wrapper`, you can actually rebind it to a different reference from the one you used to create it.
That means that you can create a *reference* like object to *use later*, as you asked.

Here is a minimal, working example:

```
#include<functional>
#include<vector>
#include<cassert>

int main() {
    int x;
    std::reference_wrapper<int> w{x};
    std::vector<int> vec{1, 2, 3};
    w = vec[0];
    w.get() = 42;
    assert(vec[0] == 42);
}
```

Again, this is for the sake of curiosity.
I do not suggest you to do it in your code (unless you hate your colleagues, of course).